# msxml3.dll error '800c0005'

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, asp-classic, windows-server-2008

Really weird problem, I have just moved all our sites to a new Win2008 64bit server with IIS7 (Was on a Win2003 IIS6) and have started having problems with PayPal Pro / PayFlow.

A few of these websites are stores with SSL's and use PayPal Pro to process the payment - Since the move, intermittently I am getting errors like.

> msxml3.dll error '800c0005'  The
>   system cannot locate the resource
>   specified.

Where it seems I cannot connect resolve the PayPal URL to post the data to, as I say this has only started happening since we are on this new server. And what is even more annoying is that its completely intermittent!! Works fine for hours then will throw this error over and over then will be fine again, it effects both the Classic ASP and ASP.NET C# sites using PayPal??

Here is a log file entry if that helps?

> 2010-07-05 11:34:07 80.100.200.155
>   POST /scripts/60_Pay.asp
>   |297|800c0005|The_system_cannot_locate_the_resource_specified.__
>   443 - 92.8.25.196
>   Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.0;+WOW64;+Sky+Broadband;+GTB6.5;+SLCC1;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+Media+Center+PC+5.0;+.NET+CLR+3.5.21022;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+MDDC;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729)
>   500 0 0 1907

Anyone have any ideas on what could be causing this? I was wondering if there was a way to increase the length of time it will wait to try and resolve from the external URL?

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the application pool that you are running this under to run in 32 bit mode and restart IIS.  This will at least remove one variable.

Next you should check to see if you can write a very simple asp page that instantiates the xmlhttp object and tries to load a URL to make sure you don't have a network configuration that is preventing the new machine from reaching PayPal's servers (but which allowed the old machine to do so).  This could be on your side, or their side.

Finally, are you able to run the code under a debugger on the server so you can figure out what line the error is happening on?